# How to execute API update password in jMeter Load test

Tags: api, jmeter, passwords, counter

I'm a newbie with jMeter. I would to ask opinion and guide from forum to point me to right direction. I've have been tasked to do Load test on API Update Password. I have try several approach I can think off plus with the info from internet, but failed to have successful execution.
Below is my most successful approach but still failed after 3-5 minutes execution.

[image: 1]

**Test Plan**

CSV Data Set Config - (Default setting, contain 500 member id's)

**Thread Group** (Setting: 100vu/100s, Loop: Infinite, Duration: 1 hour)

> Counter1 (Old Password) example: abc001

> Counter2 (New Password) example: abc002

> > Http Request (Get Token) {

> > Old Password

> > Member Id } --> Send token to next http request

> > Http Request (Update Password) {

> > Old Password

> > New Password

> > Confirm New Password }

The both Counter have increment of 1 and checked for Track counter independently for each user.

Based on my logic, it should be able to handle the execution as below.

Member1 (abc001,abc002) > Member1 (abc002,abc003) > Member1 (abc003,abc004) > etc

But in reality if failed. I also have try using JSR223 for counter, but still failed. Please help me by pointing me to correct direction how to execute this. I hope anyone can help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its current form your question doesn't make a lot of sense, it's unclear to me what is expected behaviour, what is the actual one, how exactly your test is failing [and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Try running it with [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) added so you would see the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) with their respective values.

If it doesn't help - come up with a minimal test plan which shows the issue you're having using i.e. [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-dummy-sampler) and indicate what's wrong and how it should behave according to your expectations.

Comment: Hi Dimitri. Thank you for the suggestion. I've try it and found where the problem is. After that I try looking solution, found the method that work for me here : https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/49211/how-to-increment-alphanum-value-in-jmeter-inside-a-loop-counter. Thank you again Dimitri.